# Why am I getting SSLError in google-analytics in iOS 9.3.2 and 10.0.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, ssl-certificate

I have integrated Google Analytics 3.15. It is working fine for all other iOS versions than iOS 9.3.2 and 10.0.1. I am getting following error in to this.

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
Dispatch error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x1701157b0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
"<cert(0x1018ed200) s: *.google-analytics.com i: Google Internet Authority G2>",
"<cert(0x1018efa00) s: Google Internet Authority G2 i: GeoTrust Global CA>",
"<cert(0x1018f0200) s: GeoTrust Global CA i: Equifax Secure Certificate Authority>"
```

I have setup Info.plist on the basis of following analysis. On Terminal I have hit following command:

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://ssl.google-analytics.com
```

[image]

I have got one more information by hitting following command.

```
curl -kvI https://ssl.google-analytics.com
```

Output of the above command:
[image]

Please find my info.plist for ATS:
[image]
I have tried with following links:

- [iOS9 GoogleAnalytics and NSAppTransportSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579507/ios9-googleanalytics-and-nsapptransportsecurity)
- [Google Analytics (iOS SDK) without SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692877/google-analytics-ios-sdk-without-ssl)
- [App TranSport security, allow arbitrary load not working after upgrade to IOS 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509013/app-transport-security-allow-arbitrary-load-not-working-after-upgrade-to-ios-10)

Please help me to understand what is the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Found this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13472.   Doesn't really match what you are seeing but mentions that if you turn on requires forward secrecy the requirement for sha2/sh256 is relaxed.  It looks like the cert is sha256 but out of curiosity I wonder what would happen if you turned on requires forward secrecy?

Comment: Did you try updating the SDK? The latest version is 3.17.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778579/kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9802-when-connecting-to-a-server-by-ip-address-through

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments but after lots of research I came to know that reason for error.I have fixed by just changing the Date and Time of iPhone to Automatic from Manual.I know it's very simple fix but it took 5 days to analyze and fix.